# How do I inline images between text in a Table?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, eclipse

I have a `Table` and a `Label` with wrapped text.
I want to display some images in-line with the text. For example:

> This is an image -IMAGE_HERE-, and now some more text showing, yet, another image -IMAGE_HERE-.

I tried using one `Label` containing all the text and spaces for the images, then draw the sprites. However, I can't get the locations I should draw the sprite in to fill those spaces. I could hard-code the values, but they'll vary per device. I also tried adding multiple labels with images between, but that didn't work out either.

Is there a way of fixing this, say by calculating words' widths? Is it possible to have text with inline images in a `Table`?

---

if you are wondering why I'm using a `Table`: The `Label` text should fit on screen regardless of device resolution. I've found a `Table` helps with this: I just set `bounds` and `size` and it works.

Comment: @Anko Thanks for the edit, I posted this late at night so I couldn't think very well, then I just left it xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find any help with my issue so I resorted to adding multiple `Labels` and using the `Label`'s `X`, `Y`, `width` and `height` to set the position of the `Sprite`.

I also require an animation which I don't think is possible in a `Table`, so I will have to just do this.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Use an `Image` instance instead of `Sprite` because `Image` extends `Actor` and can be added to a `Table` as an individual actor.
Then split the content to be displayed on your screen into four pieces: one for the first bit of text, one for the first `Image`, one for the second bit of text, and the last for the second `Image`.
Add these actors to different cells in the same row in the table:

```
table.add(label1);
table.add(image1);
table.add(label2);
table.add(image2);
```

You can then play with various layout/spacing/sizing effects in the table as you see fit for your case. Just type in `"."` on the `add(actor)` method and then hit `Ctrl + Space` to see what functionality it provides.

You might also want to check out the following link which provides a pretty nice description of the `TableLayout`: [TableLayout](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/tablelayout).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Reason for me using a `Sprite` is I set a rotation/size which I don't think can be done with an `Image`, I have actually played around with the methods and looked at various sources on the internet, but I can't seem to get it working the way I want it to. But I have found another solution to this, which I don't particularly like. But works.